# Scaling Azure SQL database will make my website goes down?

Tags: azure-sql-database, scalability

I have a website using Azure SQL databases, and I have some questions:

1. How does the scaling process work? Is there a flow, diagram that illustrates it?
2. Will the scaling cause any downtime in my website?
3. Am I able to write things to the database during the scaling process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. How does the scaling process work? Is there a flow, diagram that
   illustrates it?
   See this link:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tiers
2. Will the scaling cause any downtime in my website?

No new connections for a brief period and existing connections might rollback.

> Changing the service tier and/or performance level of a database
>   creates a replica of the original database at the new performance
>   level, and then switches connections over to the replica. No data is
>   lost during this process but during the brief moment when we switch
>   over to the replica, connections to the database are disabled, so some
>   transactions in flight may be rolled back. This window varies, but is
>   on average under 4 seconds, and in more than 99% of cases is less than
>   30 seconds. If there are large numbers of transactions in flight at
>   the moment connections are disabled, this window may be longer.

3. Am I able to write things to the database during the scaling
   process?

Yes but you might see your transaction is rolled back.

Comment: Is this different between DTO based options and vCore?  It seems like vCore separate storage with compute, so you can add core independent of storage.  Would this reduce the need to create a replica?

Comment: I do not think so. Reading this it appears same effect.[Scale single database resources in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-single-database-scale)  and [Dynamically scale database resources with minimal downtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-scale-resources).

Comment: Can confirm, rescaling mid query will roll back the query.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and its very bad .. most of the times it drops connections during scaling up/down , I don't recommend to do this if your database is loaded it may take too huge time